# Is there an indexed list in Haskell and is it good or bad?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

I am a new comer to the Haskell world and I am wondering if there is something like this:

```
data IndexedList a = IList Int [a]

findIndex::(Int->Int)->IndexedList a->(a,IndexedList a)
findIndex f (IList x l) = (l!!(f x), IList (f x) l)

next::IndexedList a->(a,IndexedList a)
next x = findIndex (+1) x
```

I've noticed that this kind of list is not purely functional but kind of useful for some applications. Should it be considered harmful?

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Why is this not purely functional?

Comment: @TomEllis I thought it hides the side effect of manipulating the index?

Comment: You're not actually modifying anything though. The concept of data encapsulation is separate from the concept of a side effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's certainly useful to have a list that comes equipped with a pointed to a particular location in the list. However, the way it's usually done in Haskell is somewhat different - rather than using an explicit pointer, we tend to use a *zipper*.

The list zipper looks like this

```
data ListZipper a = LZ [a] a [a] deriving (Show)
```

You should think of the  middle field `a` as being the element that is currently pointed to, the first field `[a]` as being the elements before the current position, and the final field `[a]` as being the elements after the current position.

Usually we store the elements before the current one in reverse order, for efficiency, so that the list `[0, 1, 2, *3*, 4, 5, 6]` with a pointer to the middle element, would be stored as

```
LZ [2,1,0] 3 [4,5,6]
```

You can define functions that move the pointer to the left or right

```
left  (LZ (a:as) b bs) = LZ as a (b:bs)
right (LZ as a (b:bs)) = LZ (a:as) b bs
```

If you want to move to the left or right `n` times, then you can do that with the help of a function that takes another function, and applies it `n` times to its argument

```
times n f = (!!n) . iterate f
```

so that to move left three times, you could use

```
>> let lz = LZ [2,1,0] 3 [4,5,6]
>> (3 `times` left) lz
LZ [] 0 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Your two functions `findIndex` and `next` can be written as

```
next :: ListZipper a -> (a, ListZipper a)
next = findIndex 1

findIndex :: Int -> ListZipper a -> (a, ListZipper a)
findIndex n x = let y@(LZ _ a _) = (n `times` right) x in (a, y)
```

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to what you think this list is in fact purely functional. The reason is that `IList (f x) l` creates a new list (and does not, as you may think, modify the current IndexedList). It is in general not that easy to create non-purely functional data structures or functions in Haskell, as long as you stay away from `unsafePerformIO`.

The reason I would recommend against using the `IndexedList` is that there is no assurance that the index is less than the length of the list. In this case the lookup `l!!(f x)` will fail with an exception, which is generally considered bad style in Haskell. An alternative could be to use a safe lookup, which returns a `Maybe a` like the following:

```
findIndex :: (Int -> Int) -> IndexedList a -> (Maybe a, IndexedList a)
findIndex f (IList i l) = (maybe_x, IList new_i l)
    where
        new_i   = f i
        maybe_x = if new_i < length l 
                  then Just (l !! newI) 
                  else Nothing
```

I can also not think of a usecase where such a list would be useful, but I guess I am limited by my creativity ;)

Comment: Thanks, I am going through H99 and one use case of it can be found in https://gist.github.com/dorafmon/de91787391005a6bfddd